# RIO (Registered I/O) sockets in .NET

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-8, windows-server-2012

Are there any plans by the .NET team to make the RIO sockets that were introduced in Windows 8/Server 2012 available in .NET?

What are my options in the interim to utilize them from within .NET - extend the Socket class?

Apart from the Windows API documentation, [What's New for Windows Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and a Channel9 video, [New Techniques to Develop Low-Latency Network Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/SAC-593T), I can barely find any further documentation about them.

Comment: You could probably [check out this series on RIO and translate them to P/Invoke for starters](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io-example-udp-servers.html).

Answer (score 5):

I've written quite a lot about my initial investigations into RIO from native code [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/rio/) (as the commenter to your original question pointed out).

I'd be interested to know what you're hoping to achieve by using RIO from managed code? RIO's likely target audience are developers who need to reduce latency in their networking code. Personally I'm not convinced that managed code is necessarily ideal for the kind of applications that RIO was aimed at; I may be wrong, but I'd expect that having the chance that the CLR could trigger a garbage collection at any point would not be the kind of thing that someone using RIO would want...

Anyway. I think that if you wanted to use RIO from managed code then I'd recommend NOT simply using P/Invoke and instead writing a component that manages all of the RIO work in native code and that, perhaps, calls back into managed on various network events. But again, that's just how I'd do it...

Comment: I work in the financial industry and while I agree that we would be able to squeeze out a little more performance writing native code, we were able to develop a managed application stack that is largely GC free, with low jitter and low latency. The particular component that I would be using RIO for has a mean latency of 5usec per processed packet but incurs a ~20usec hit per call on the user to kernel mode transition to winsock. If we could bring that down via RIO that would seem like an instant win without having to go the kernel bypass route. - Thanks for the links to your articles!

Comment: Sounds like it's worth looking into then.

Comment: @TJF how did you make your server GC free and reduce latency as well?

Comment: Answers closed but investigation into using RIO from managed code: http://www.ageofascent.com/azure-cloud-high-speed-networking/ also code that article refers to: https://github.com/benaadams/benchmarks/tree/managed-rio-experimental/experimental/ManagedRIOHttpServer

Answer (score 4):

RIO is being investigated experimentally for the "channels" API, currently in an inception / exploration stage, but usable from here: https://github.com/davidfowl/Channels. This is alongside a libuv API, and a "channels"-based winsock API. With respect to your question about extending the socket class: the nature of these APIs seems to make a different approach desirable - hence "channels".

Comment: And the 2.1 release of RIO was mentioned in this ASP.NET Community Standup video (plan is to NOT ship it in 2.1, still TBD in Pipelines/SignalR Core):  
https://youtu.be/ySmUI8O1Rog?t=10m30s at 10:30